# how do I perform a DIV operation in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, division

I'm new to Assembly and I need to convert this C code:

```
rowScreen=((indexMat/10)*2)+7;
colScreen=((indexMat%10)*4)+7;
gotoxyP1()
```

The idea is to modify those 2 global variables, but I don't understand how the DIV operation works, this is my routine now:

```
posCurScreenP1:
    push rbp
    mov  rbp, rsp
    push rax
    push rbx

    mov al, [indexMat]
    mov bl,10
    idiv bl

        ; ... something needs to go here

    call gotoxyP1

    pop rbx
    pop rax
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Any help/tutorial that shows a simple operation with DIV/IDIV? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried generating an assembly listing from the C code?

Comment: [8086 assembly on DOSBox: Bug with idiv instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/a/43575674) and [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/a/38416896) explain how to use signed or unsigned division instructions.  Your current code is already broken because you don't sign-extend `indexMat` into AX.  Use `movsx eax, byte [indexMax]` before byte-size `idiv`.  But are you sure you want signed division instead of zero-extension + `div`?

Comment: _"I don't understand how the DIV operation works"_ Did you look it up in Intel's manual? What about the description was unclear?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm just learning how it's working and I think I finally found out what was wrong, I will post a solution, feel free to tell me if it's correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
    push r8
    push r9

    mov r8, 7
    mov r9, 10


    mov ax, [indexMat]
    mov bl,10
    div bl

    mov [rowScreen], al ;rowScreen = (indexMat/10)
    mov [colScreen], ah ;colScreen = (indexMat%10)


    mov bl,2
    mul bl
    mov [rowScreen], ax ;rowScreen = (indexMat/10)*2
    add [rowScreen], r8 ; rowScreen = (indexMat/10)*2 +7


    mov al, [colScreen]
    mov bl, 4
    mul bl
    mov [colScreen], ax
    add [colScreen], r9

    ...
```

Maybe it's not optimal but I think it works.

Comment: Now `indexMat` is a word, not a byte?  If it's >= 2560, your code will fault with a #DE divide overflow (because the quotient won't fit in AL).  Also, you don't need `mul` to scale by 2.  Just do `shl ax, 1`.  (Well you have to zero AH first because you have garbage there).  Anyway, normally don't use `mul` or `div` for powers of 2, use shifts.